# select Oracle Table from toad without specifying the Schema

Tags: oracle11g

Hi Guys I am running an Oracle DB and I have to Write the Schema(Owner) name before selecting the Table. I find this Quite Unnecessary especially when am Logged in as the Table Owner Like:

```
select * from MUNGAI.Employees;
```

When am Actually Logged in as user MUNGAI the same Who Created the table. I want to be able to select like:

```
select * from Empployees;
```

From this I get the Error On Toad....On SQLDEVELOPER I get No Error and I want to Use TOAD

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Any Ideas on How to Achieev this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I have to Write the Schema(Owner) name before selecting the Table.*

No, you don't have to. Why do you think so? Did you even try it?

When you are logged in as the owner of the table you do not have to specify the schema.

> *Any Ideas on How to Achieev this??*

Yes, simply write

```
select * from Employees;
```

Again: this works **if** - and only if<sup>1)</sup>) - you are logged in as `MUNGAI`.

<sup>1) leaving things like public synonyms aside</sup>

Comment: I get the Error Table or view does not exist Only on Toad in SQLDeveloper it comes fine.

Comment: @Stanley: Then you are **not** connecting as the table owner in TOAD - which means this is actually a TOAD question, not an Oracle question.

Comment: Sorry I think you are right I am Loggin In as MUNGAI but connecting as SYSDBA...Thanks.